# $\frac{1}{2a^2+3}+\frac{1}{2b^2+3}+\frac{1}{2c^2+3}\geq\frac{3}{5}.$

Tags: inequality

Let $a, b, c \in\mathbb{R}, a, b,c\geq \frac{1}{4}$ and $a+b+c=3$.

Show that $\frac{1}{2a^2+3}+\frac{1}{2b^2+3}+\frac{1}{2c^2+3}\geq\frac{3}{5}.$

My idea: $(4a-1)(a-1)^2\geq 0$. Then I tried to divide $4a^3-9a^2+6a-1$  by $2a^2+3$ but I am stuck.

Comment: Solutions on AoPS: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h2428115p20026931, https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1561488p9548802

Comment: FWIW Your idea is great. You just have to relate it back to $\frac{1}{2a^2 + 3 } $. EG $ \frac{1}{2a^2 + 3 } - \frac{ 9 - 4x } { 25 } = \frac{ 2(4a-1)(a-1)^2} { 25(2x^2 + 3 ) } $ per Sayaj's solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP said that they tried to consider $ \frac{ (4a-1)(a-1)^2}{2a^2 + 3 } \geq 0$, but got stuck.

To continue from there, observe that via partial fractions:

$$ 0 \leq \frac{ (4a-1)(a-1)^2}{2a^2 + 3 } = \frac{25}{2(2a^2 + 3) } + 2a - \frac{9}{2}.$$

So, summing across all variables, we get that

$$ \sum \frac{ 25}{2(2a^2 + 3 ) } \geq \frac{ 27}{2} - 2 \sum a = \frac{15}{2} . $$

Hence, the desired result follows.

---

Note: While in this case, the result is essentially that of the tangent-line approach (EG See Sahaj's solution), note that in order cases we could have gotten a quadratic quotient.

Comment: @Sahaj Sorry, Autocorrect changed it.

Answer (score 1):

Set $f(x) = \frac1{2x^2+3}$. Note that $f''(x) = \frac{12(2x^2-1)}{(2x^2+3)^3}$. Further $f''(x) >0$ for $x \gt \frac1{\sqrt 2}$. So the tangent to $f(x)$ at $x=1$ ie $g(x) = \frac{9-4x}{25}$ always lies below $f(x)$ when $x > \frac1{\sqrt 2}$ with intersection at $x=1$. I leave it to you to show that $f(x) \geq g(x)$ for $x \in [\frac14, \frac1{\sqrt 2}]$. Simple factoring or argument via derivatives should suffice.

With that it follows $$f(a)+f(b)+f(c) \geq g(a)+g(b)+g(c) = \frac{27-12}{25} = \frac{3}{5}$$

Note equality is attained at $(1,1,1)$.

Comment: Side note: In the first paragraph, it's easier to just say that $f(x) \geq g(x) $ on $ x \in [ 1/4, \infty)$ through factoring.

Comment: @CalvinLin, agreed. I realized that later on whilst writing the answer, so I just left it out to the reader to prove it by factoring.

Answer (score 0):

**Another proof:**

It's enough to prove:
$$\frac{1}{2a^2+3}+\frac{1}{2b^2+3} \ge \frac{4}{(a+b)^2+6}$$
Which is equaivalent to:
$$(a-b)^2(2a^2+8ab+2b^2-6) \ge 0$$

So, the first inequality can be written as:
$$\frac{4}{(a+b)^2+6}+\frac{1}{2c^2+3} \ge \frac{3}{5}$$
$$\Leftrightarrow \frac{4}{(3-c)^2+6}+\frac{1}{2c^2+3} \ge \frac{3}{5}$$
$$\Leftrightarrow \frac{6c(4 - c)(c - 1)^2}{5(c^2 - 6c + 15)(2c^2 + 3)} \ge 0$$
which is obvious since $c \le \frac{5}{2}$